# Can accepts_nested_attributes_for be used without a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class Users < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club
end
```

My understanding is that I should be able to do this to add a user to a club:

```
c = Club.first
p = { :users_attributes => [{:id => 1, :club_id => 2}] }
c.update(p)
```

When I do this, I receive the following error:

```
2.4.1 :003 > c.update(p)
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."club_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" = 1  [["club_id", 2]]
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=1 for Club with ID=2
```

Rails appears to be checking if the user is already a member of the club before allowing me to update the user.

It works if I try to modify a user that is already in the club to another club.

I think I could work around this by creating a join table, but I'd rather not. Help!

Comment: Can a user be a member of more than one club? Or is the user simply a member of 1 club at the time?

Comment: Nope. The users table has a club_id field.

Comment: Ok, then I see what you're trying to do

Comment: Any idea how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

`accept_nested_attributes` is used when you want to save multiple objects at the same time / through the same form through the parent-model. I don't even see why you'd need to have `has_many :users` on Club since no users are actually being built from Club. User's belonging to a club could simply be iterated trough anyways by simply doing:

```
clubs/show.html.erb 

<% Users.all.where(:club_id => @club.id).each do |user| %>
```

And you'd get all users that are members of the club.

And since all you wish to do here is update the `club_id` on the User, you don't even need to accept_nested_attributes, let alone creating a join table. (Unless you wish to update both of them at the same time). But from what I can see, all you'd have to do in this case is create a `form_for @user` that passes the @club.id, like this:

Let's say you're on the show page of club or iterating through the Club object where the @club.id is accessible:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(current_user, as: current_user, url: update_user_path(current_user), html: { method: :patch}) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field :club_id, :value => @club.id %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Join Club!" %>
<% end %>
```

And voilá. User now has the desired club_id.

If you wish to do it through the console, just do:

```
x = User.find(1)
x.update(club_id: 1)
```

If you wish to add/remove multiple users, just do:

```
x = User.find(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
x.update(club_id: 1)
```

If you wish to use different club_ids for multiple different users, you can do:

```
x = { 1 => { "club_id" => 1 }, 2 => { "club_id" => 2 } }
User.update(x.keys, x.values)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update

Comment: There are several ways I could do what I want to do without accepts_nested_attributes_for. But I'm trying to understand how accepts_nested_attributes_for works in the case there is no join table.

Let's say I want to add 1 user, and remove 1 user from a club with a single params hash. I think that should be possible using accepts_nested_attributes_for. Something like: { :users_attributes => [{:id => 1, :club_id => 2}, {:id => 2, :club_id => nil}] }

Comment: But I'm not seeing how that would apply in any real world programatic case to be honest given that no User object is ever created from a club... Unless you wish to create a user and a club at the same time. Then accept_nested_attributes_for would be a solution. Although not strictly necessary.  There are other solutions I'd personally much rather would prefer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, and you have added a solution to the hypothetical I proposed in the question, but it doesn't answer whether accepts_nested_attributes_for can be used in this sort of circumstance without a join table which is what I really wanted to know. How should I proceed?

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for can be used in these circumstances without a join table, Yes. Let's say we're not talking about clubs and users but Comments and Notifications. First, you'd want to make sure upon Comment AND Notification creation that the Notification is built from the Comment using Comment.notifications.build. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: I am. But I'm really just interested in the update use case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151113/discussion-between-crashtor-and-keith-carter).